# Error reading char values from a .txt file into an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I have to write a program that reads single char values from a .txt file into an array. When I run the code it displays a bunch of weird symbols.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
const int NUM_ANS = 10;
char answers[NUM_ANS], student[NUM_ANS];


ifstream correctAnswers;
correctAnswers.open("C:\\Users\\RCLRC115\\Desktop\\student.txt");
int count = 0;
while (count < NUM_ANS && correctAnswers >> answers[count])
    count++;

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ANS; i++) {
    cout << answers[i] << endl;
}

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably not the bug, but your second loop should have the condition `i < count`.

Comment: No because it's not a nested loop, by the end of the loop count and NUM_ANS both hold 10 as their value, and I prefer to use NUM_ANS because it will be a constant through out my program.

Comment: If the file can't be found, or contains garbage, or less than 10 characters (you *did* mean to just read 10 characters, not 10 lines?) then your code will print garbage characters. Changing the second loop to use `count` means you'll only print what you read in.

Comment: no, I meant to read 10 lines... how would I go about so it reads 10 lines instead?

Comment: You meant to read 10 *lines*? Can you show us the contents of `student.txt` please?

Answer (score 2):

You re opening the file incorrectly.

It should be

```
correctAnswers.open("C:\\Users\\RCLRC115\\Desktop\\student.txt");
```

You have to escape `\` character

Comment: Or better yet just use forward slashes

Comment: I scaped all \\ characters now but it still shows random symbols

Comment: Try calling `correctAnswers.is_open()` to see if the file was opened and displaying the value `count` before the loop (and looping up to `count` instead of `NUM_ANS`).

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me that `correctAnswers.open` fails because the path you use is wrong. Remember that in C and C++ you must escape the `\` character by typing it as `\\` when inside a string.

There is an important lesson here: always check that operations succeed. `ifstream::is_open` exists and returns a value for a reason. :)

Comment: I used if (correctAnswers.is_open()) and it shows it's not opening the files, I just don't understand why. I even tried changing the path of student.txt to be inside the project folder and that way I dont have to write all the path but it still not opening the file :/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using comments, and some form of error catching. Even if it just displays a message that there was an error, and what that error was. Try this it worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int NUM_ANS = 10;
    char answers[NUM_ANS], student[NUM_ANS];

    // would recommend: 'ifstream fin;' because its shorter
    ifstream correctAnswers;

    // open the txt file
    // ifstream.open(const char* Filename, std::ios_base::open_mode _Mode);
    // use 'ios_base::in' for input, and 'ios_base::out' for output
    // it tells the ifstream how to file should be opened. In this case for input.
    correctAnswers.open("C:/Users/RCLRC115/Desktop/student.txt", ios_base::in);

    // check that the last ifstream operation didn't fail.
    if (correctAnswers.fail())
    {
        // print error message
        cout << "ERROR: Could not open file!";
        cin.get();

        // Return a value other than 0 so you'll know there was an error by looking
        // at the output window
        // The program '[#] programName.exe: Native' has exited with code 1
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // print success message
        cout << "SUCCESS: File Opened! Reading File..." << '\n';
    }

    int count = 0;

    // 'while (count < NUM_ANS && correctAnswers << answers[count])' is where one error was
    // 'while (count < NUM_ANS)' is correct. correctAnswers << answers[count] is telling it to store
    // the read characters in answers[count], not checking if the character was read, and valid.

    // Basically saying:
    // 'while (count < NUM_ANS)' AND 'while (ifstream.good())' 
    // meaning the input file stream read a character and not the end of file.
    while (count < NUM_ANS && correctAnswers.good())
    {
        // this is where the other error was, it probably wasn't storing anything in answers[count]
        // store the values read in answers[count]
        correctAnswers >> answers[count];
        // increment count so loop will end
        count++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ANS; i++) 
    {
        // print the value in the command window
        cout << answers[i] << endl;
    }

    // Make sure to close files open with ifstream, ofstream, and iofstream
    correctAnswers.close();

    // Wait to get input so window doesn't close
    cin.get();

    // Return 0, program exited normally
    return 0;
}
```